# Ascending chain of monotone classes, $A$ necessarily in $\mathcal{M}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{M}_1 \subset \mathcal{M}_2 \subset \ldots$ are monotone classes. Let $\mathcal{M} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \mathcal{M}_n$. Suppose $A_j \uparrow A$ and each $A_j \in \mathcal{M}$. Is $A$ necessarily in $\mathcal{M}$?

Answer (score 2):

If the set of $A_n$ is actually finite, then there's a greatest one — $A_N$, say — and then of course $A = A_N \in \mathcal{M}$.

So suppose there are infinitely many $A_n$. Without loss of generality we can assume all $A_n$ are distinct, so that if $i < j$ then $A_i \subsetneqq A_j$. In this case, let $\mathcal{M}_n = \{A_i\mid 1\le i\le n\}$. Then each $\mathcal{M}_n$ is a monotone class, and if $i < j$ then $\mathcal{M}_i \subsetneqq \mathcal{M}_j$. (I assume that your $\subset$ means $\subsetneqq$.) Then $A = \bigcup_n A_n$ is not in $\mathcal{M} = \bigcup_n \mathcal{M}_n$, because $A$ is not in any $\mathcal{M}_n$.